# Spring Boot App log file is being saved to the parent directory instead of project directory

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I created an **Empty Project** in Intellij IDEA and added my Spring Boot projects via **Import Module**. Now I'm incorporating logging to my apps. I added the following configuration to one of my apps (API Gateway)

```
logging:
  file:
    name: api-gateway.log
```

*I am expecting that the log file will be created/stored at the app's root directory.*
However, the log file was saved in the main project's root directory.

[image]

I tried adding path but log file is not generating.

```
logging:
  file:
    name: api-gateway.log
    path: spring-cloud-api-gateway
```

I would like to know if this is the default behavior when an app is imported to an empty project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and sharing here for reference. Edit your **Run/Debug Configurations** and specify the Working directory. Leaving it **blank** defaults the the Parent Project root directory.
[image]